# How can I get use rebase instead of merge?

Tags: git

I have two branches dev and master with 1 conflict when I get the difference I get:

```
-    if (1 == 1) {
-console.log('hi from master')
+    if (1 != 1) {
+console.log('hi from dev')
     }
```

When I go: git merge master, I get : Already-up-to-date? If I want to merge these 2, can I use rebase instead of merge? When I do git rebase master I get:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: first commit
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   app.js
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging app.js
```

After this I still have the same difference?

See more code:
github:[more code](https://github.com/dimitri-a/gitstuff)

Comment: That's not a *conflict*.  That's just a *difference*.  Conflicts only occur when you *combine two or more differences*.

Comment: Ok how to handle differences with a rebase?

Comment: Rebase *copies* commits, and then abandons the originals after the copy succeeds. The copying process uses a three-way merge if necessary. Read some of my many other StackOverflow answers on git rebase.

Comment: So when I merge why do I get already up to date when there are 2 differences? How can I force to get a merge dialog?

Comment: Rebasing is about *redoing changes* (cherry-picking to copy), atop some existing starting point.  Merging is about *combining changes* when you and the other developer *started from a common base*, and you *both* made changes since then. You are getting the "already up to date" message because you are not starting from an earlier point. You have, after rebasing, now started from what they have now and made changes. There is nothing to merge: you already *have* all their code, plus your additional changes. You may want to undo your rebase; if so, see existing StackOverflow postings about this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your local `master` branch is up-to-date with the remote?

You can try running from `dev`:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

Or alternatively

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout dev
git merge master
```

to ensure that your local `master` branch is up-to-date with the remote.

Comment: I know that , just wanted to see if I could do it with a rebase. Is it possible do it with a rebase?

Comment: Git rebase master?

Comment: But it wont merge properly see above